# java string intern and char value[] object of String class

Tags: java, string

I am high school java learner,went through a lot of discussions but still not getting clarity on the below question.
The String intern function says that if String object is not present inside String pool it will create one and returns reference to it.Can there be a case when a created String object with new operator i.e. String s=new String("def"),it is not present in the String pool before interning? If not,why does the definition of intern() is like this?
Thanks

Comment: All String literals go to the string pool. You have a string literal `"abc"`.

Comment: OK.Can there be a case when you have a string object on heap and for the same string value ,it is not present inside the String pool.The intern function says"if not present ,it will creteate String in the String pool".So it can never be like a String object is on heap but not in String pool.

Comment: Of course. If you construct a string without using string literals, then the resulting string will be on heap, but not in the string pool.

Comment: @Kayaman
String str=new String("def");
here "def"  is not present on String pool ,,,right?

Comment: No, I said **without** string literals. You have a string literal `"def"` there.

Comment: OK.How to create String object without literals?Is this possible?

Comment: With a `char[]` for example.

Comment: `String str = new String("def");` The literal `def` is in the pool, the String `str`, created by `new` is not in the pool.  `str == "def"` will result in false, Another way to create a String: `String def = "d"; def += "ef"` or some method like `"Xdef".substring(1)`.